# Searcing for times and topics present in YouTube description

Tags: javascript, regex, string

About a couple of weeks ago, I started learning about Regular Expressions. For practice, I thought of extracting different topics(along with their respective times) present in the description section in youtube videos(youtube uses this to slice the progress bar and each slice represents different topic).
Example: for  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4M_IQG0d9g, the description looks something like below

```
00:00:00 - Introduction
00:00:15 - Machine Learning
00:01:15 - Supervised Learning
.
.
00:59:42 - scikit-learn
01:09:57 - Reinforcement Learning
By course's end, students emerge with experience in libraries for machine learning as well as knowledge of artificial intelligence principles that enable them to design intelligent systems of their own.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list...

***

This is CS50, Harvard University's introduction to the intellectual enterprises of computer science and the art of programming.
```

---

So, first I was looking for a regex to do this directly but soon realised that coming up with a single regex that does this would be very difficult because there is no strict pattern the these must follow.

Here are some other formats that I found:

```
0:00 Caden’s Hills - ‘Livin’ it Up’  <-------------
https://spoti.fi/3itjBFj
https://www.instagram.com/cadens_hill...
Download: https://apple.co/3adwC2U
2:39 ROMES - ‘Lose My Cool’          <-------------
https://spoti.fi/2XJY2Zp
https://www.instagram.com/romes/?hl=en
Download: https://apple.co/3affRV3
```

---

```
⌨️ (1:40:38) Sine and Cosine of Special Angles
⌨️ (1:48:41) Unit Circle Definition of Sine and Cosine
⌨️ (1:54:11) Properties of Trig Functions
⌨️ (1:04:50) Graphs of Sine and Cosine
```

---

```
incermenting numbers 15:30
decrementing numbers15:59 // this is not a mistake.. there is no space.
decimal numbers 16:23
```

---

```
01 - 00:00 - Into the sun (Sons Of The East)
02 - 03:48 - Looking too Closely (Fink)
03 - 07:20 - Numb/Encore (Linkin Park & Jay Z)
```

---

So, as you can see to come up with one regex to do this accurately is difficult. So I did some more thinking and reading. And I came up with the below solution:

```js
let input = `
some text I dont care about
...
lalalalla
mr white....
by order of hte foooking peaky blinders
destiny is all..

A blank stare grown on her face
She lost her soul and hope
She no longer feels the pain
She's having a love affair with dope
No more posey's an ring around the rosey
No more midnight rides to fly
Her new love Is jealous an clingy
Won't hesitate to let her die
With every intimate moment they have
With all there time shared together
Chasing her faded  youth to hell
The dope let death finally get her
----------------------------
// this is ehat I care about
Lecture 0:00

[First piece]
Elimination pivots and an example 

3:09
    - Failure of Elimination method 10:34
14:50

[Second piece]
Operations of matrices elimination 19:24
Row operations of Matrices Multiplication 20:22
Column operations of Matrices multiplication 21:43

[Third piece]
Elementary Matrix 24:33
    - 
    - Second step :  29:28
    - Over 32:10

Associative law in matrix  33:29
Permutation matrix 36:56
    - Row example: 37:36
 
Commutative law : Matrix order 41:17

Inverse matrix: 43:00


lalalalalalfdklfndklsfds
pinkman:i love science beach...
dfdskfndksfd
the end of the f**king world
`

let regex = /((?:\d{1,2})?(?::\d{1,2})?:\d{1,2})/; 
let arr = input.split(/[\r\n]+/); // split


let time =[];
let labels = [];
arr.forEach(e => {
  let match;
   if (match = regex.exec(e)){ // for all the elements of the array that matches this
  
  //get the number of characters before the match is found in the string
  beforeLength = match.index  
  // get the number of characters after the match
  afterLenght =  e.length - ( match.index + match[1].length )
  
  // I already have the match (time)  so put that into time array 
  time.push(match[1]);
  
  //here I am making this assumption: there is more probabily that label is present on the side that has more number of characters
  //(i also thought of randomly selecting 3 elements from the array and then select a side based on BEST of three results before this loop and use that side for labels for each element) unlike what I am doing right now.
  if(afterLenght > beforeLength){
    labels.push(e.substring(match.index + match[1].length).trim())
  }else {
    labels.push(e.substring(0,match.index).trim());
  }

   }
});

let result = labels
// just some cleanup
if(labels.every(s => s[0] == labels[0][0])) {
  result = labels.map(s => s.substring(1).trim());
}

console.log(time)
console.log(result)
```

I know this is not perfect, one problem that I realised this would suffer is when there is something like  below in the input

```
incermenting numbers 15:30
decrem2:03enting numbers 15:50 <------
decimal numbers 16:23
```

So if a similar pattern is present in the label itself, then the regex would stop searching(because I am not using `global` flag) and I will get a wrong result.

- So, how can I make this solution better?
- How can I make this more robust?
- and If you can think of a better solution to this problem feel to share that too. I would really love to know other approaches to solve this problem

Thanks

---

Just one more thing.

This is the regex that i am using:

```
/((?:\d{1,2})?(?::\d{1,2})?:\d{1,2})/;
```

and these are the strings that I hope to match with this

```
:5           --> this is equal to 00:00:05
:45          --> 00:00:45
3:45
03:45
:03:45      
0:03:45
00:03:45
```

I have also written some code that converts any of the times to HH:MM:SS. So, using the regex I am just trying to find these patterns and later I can do the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const re = String.raw`([-a-z :]*)([:\d]+)$`;
const matches = input
  .match(new RegExp(re, 'gmi')) // we only want timestamped lines
  .map(match => match.match(new RegExp(re, 'i'))) // split into timestamp and string
  .map(([,str,time]) => ([time, str.trim()])); // only keep timestamp and string
```

Live example (but look in your browser's real console for prettier output):

```js
'use strict';

const input = `some text I dont care about
...
lalalalla
mr white....
by order of hte foooking peaky blinders
destiny is all..

A blank stare grown on her face
She lost her soul and hope
She no longer feels the pain
She's having a love affair with dope
No more posey's an ring around the rosey
No more midnight rides to fly
Her new love Is jealous an clingy
Won't hesitate to let her die
With every intimate moment they have
With all there time shared together
Chasing her faded  youth to hell
The dope let death finally get her
----------------------------
// this is ehat I care about
Lecture 0:00

[First piece]
Elimination pivots and an example 

3:09
    - Failure of Elimination method 10:34
14:50

[Second piece]
Operations of matrices elimination 19:24
Row operations of Matrices Multiplication 20:22
Column operations of Matrices multiplication 21:43

[Third piece]
Elementary Matrix 24:33
    - 
    - Second step :  29:28
    - Over 32:10

Associative law in matrix  33:29
Permutation matrix 36:56
    - Row example: 37:36
 
Commutative law : Matrix order 41:17

Inverse matrix: 43:00


lalalalalalfdklfndklsfds
pinkman:i love science beach...
dfdskfndksfd
the end of the f**king world
`;

const re = String.raw`([-a-z :]*)([:\d]+)$`;
const matches = input
  .match(new RegExp(re, 'gmi'))
  .map(match => match.match(new RegExp(re, 'i')))
  .map(([,str,time]) => ([time, str.trim()]));

console.log(matches);
```